# Will Apache automatically create a click log of pages visited on my site?

Tags: webserver, apache-log-files, click-tracking

I need the 'click data' in raw form on the webserver. Due to security reasons I can not give any access of my website to third party.

If I get the raw click log somewhere on the server, I can use that for further analysis. I would like to know

1. will the click log be automatically saved on the server (Apache)? If so, where it will be stored?
2. if not automatic, how can we enable the server to store the clicks of all users?

My aim is to get raw click stream data of pages users visit on my website.

Comment: What do you mean by click?

do you mean every url that is requested that's in the access log or more advanced on page click tracking like Google analytics does?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean exactly by a click.

If you are trying to track what part of a screen a user is clicking in general, then you'll need to use javascript click handlers along with some ajax to let the server know about the click.

If however, you want to know what links on your website a user has clicked, it will be stored in server logs. In a standard apache setup, the log you're looking for is access_log. To prove this, make a simple HTML file like this and copy every character exactly as shown:

```
<a href="testingclickthatdoesntwork">click me</a>
```

Then upload it to your server and run it in your browser and click on "click me".

Then look in access_log and you should see a line that contains:

```
testingclickthatdoesntwork
```

This will indicate its you that made the click. You'll learn the time of the click and your IP address and even the status code of the URL which may be 404. Also, you may even see the URL to the website you were at first. That's the referrer.

Comment: It would be helpful to add the directories in which you might want to look for the *access_log*.